# "Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-1.2.1-r752877:753278 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: near "FOR"" error

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa

I'm encountering this error in JPA using SQLite and I don't know why it does it, help?

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="geronimo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <class>label.entities.Discography</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:\\sqlitedb\\repo.db" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My JPA class:

```
package label.implementations;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import label.entities.Discography;



public class Disconfigurator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String persistenceUnit = "geronimo";
    EntityManagerFactory eFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit);
    EntityManager eManager = eFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction eTransaction = eManager.getTransaction();
    eTransaction.begin();
    Discography discography = new Discography();
    discography.setArtist("Kings Of Leon");
    discography.setSong("Radioactive");
    eManager.persist(discography);
    eTransaction.commit();
    eManager.close();
    eFactory.close();

}
}
```

My Entity class:

```
package label.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name="discography")
public class Discography {

@Column(name="artist",length=1000,nullable=true)
String artist;
@Column(name="song",length=1000,nullable=true)
String song;

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
}

public String getSong() {
    return song;
}

public void setSong(String song) {
    this.song = song;
}

}
```

The error trace:

```
    47  geronimo  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.1
2500  geronimo  WARN   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Your database configuration was not                             recognized as a supported OpenJPA database. The generic dictionary will be used, which may         result in limited functionality. This behavior can be overridden by specifying the     appropriate dictionary class in the "openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" property of the OpenJPA     configuration.
2500  geronimo  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class     "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary" (SQLite 3.6.3 ,SQLiteJDBC native).
2500  geronimo  WARN   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - This database dictionary "class org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary" is not officially supported by OpenJPA.
3406  geronimo  INFO   [main] openjpa.Enhance - Creating subclass for "[class label.entities.Discography]". This means that your application will be less efficient and will consume more memory than it would if you ran the OpenJPA enhancer. Additionally, lazy loading will not be available for one-to-one and many-to-one persistent attributes in types using field access; they will be loaded eagerly instead.
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-1.2.1-r752877:753278 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: near "FOR": syntax error {SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE FROM OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE} [code=0, state=null]
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:523)
at label.implementations.Disconfigurator.main(Disconfigurator.java:23)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-r752877:753278 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: near "FOR": syntax error {SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE FROM OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE} [code=0, state=null]
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4232)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4197)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:65)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignObjectId(JDBCStoreManager.java:752)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.assignObjectId(DelegatingStoreManager.java:134)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:520)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2824)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:39)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:960)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1948)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1908)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1826)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1350)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:877)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:512)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: near "FOR": syntax error {SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE FROM OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE} [code=0, state=null]
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:201)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:57)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:228)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:164)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:140)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:153)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:511)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:471)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:481)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:460)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.prepareStatement(TableJDBCSeq.java:756)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.getSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:511)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.setSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:554)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq$AllocateSequenceRunnable.run(TableJDBCSeq.java:824)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.allocateSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:424)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.nextInternal(TableJDBCSeq.java:290)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:60)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenJPA doesn't support SQLite and is generating incorrect SQL.

It's the FOR UPDATE clause that causes the problem you're seeing. You can work around it by setting OpenJPA's DBDictionary configuration property :

```
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="(forUpdateClause=)" />
```

This will only get you past the immediate exception, and there may be other properties you need to set. If you find that you have to make a lot of changes like this you might want to write your [own DBDictionary for SQLite](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_dbsetup_dbsupport).